# Flask Admin Model View Page Auto refresh

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a Flask Admin page that lists records in a database strictly for viewing (no modifications to the records).  As new records are added I would like the view to auto update without having to reload the whole page.  Is there anyway to get the Flask Admin view to do this?  I know I could just write my own template and us an ajax request script to do it.  I was just trying to see if there was something native to Flask Admin